# talked angrily to me as

Tags: meaning, commas, adverbials

a. He talked angrily to me, as to his child.

b. He talked angrily to me as to his child.

Do these mean:

1. He talked angrily to me and to his child as well.
2. He talked angrily to me in the same way he talked angrily to his child.
3. He talked angrily to me as if I were his child. (won't one need 'as if' instead of 'as' for this meaning to work?)

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Lacking any context, I would understand meaning (3). Certainly _if_ or _though_ could be included, but in literary language (which this is) they are not essential.

Comment: @KateBunting I thought that setting off "as to his child" with a comma suggests that "I" felt like the speaker's child when he talked to me, but without a comma, the sentence suggests that I and the speaker's child were both angrily talked to and probably at the same time. What do you think of this?

Comment: @EdmondKirsch - When I said 'lacking any context', I meant 'unless it was clear from the context that the man's child was also present'.  Even in that case, it would be more natural to say '_and_ to his child' - or to mention the child's name or gender!

Comment: To ***talk** angrily* is [very uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+talked+angrily%2Che+spoke+angrily&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) compared to ***speak** angrily*. And [it virtually never occurs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talked+angrily+to+me%2Cspoke+angrily+to+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) before ***...to me.***

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it pointlessly asks how native Anglophones would interpret two different non-idiomatic utterances made up by the OP

Answer (score 1):

The typical (which isn't to say the only possible) utterance is:

> He spoke to me as to **a** child.
>
> He spoke angrily to me as to **a** disobedient child.

When you substitute **his** for **a** you're making a different statement: he speaks angrily to *his* child and spoke to me in the same manner. At least that is one of the spossible interpretations.

If he does not have a child, or you don't wish to imply anything about how he speaks to his own child:

> He spoke angrily to me **as if** I were a disobedient child.